# Is there a null EtherType for packets that are only going to be handled at Layer 2?

Tags: ethernet, packet-analysis

I'm sending data into a VM via a Virtio interface, and for whatever reason I want to do Layer 2 routing with the interfaces in promiscuous mode. I know what to use as the source and destination addresses, but what should I use for the EtherType field?

Ideally, the value would also be known to WireShark and/or `tcpdump -e` so that they don't try to decode extra data from my payload. `0xFFFF` seems to be reserved, but is there a better value?

Answer (score 1):

EtherType is a mandatory field, you can't skip it. With Ethernet, you cannot use values below 0x0600 as that would indicate the payload length (up to 0x5DC) or be undefined (0x5DD-0x5FF) - see IEEE 802.3 3.2.6.

You can view the official list of EtherType values [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml#ieee-802-numbers-1). I'd suggest one of the "Local Experimental" EtherTypes for your purpose - the proper way would be to allocate an EtherType from IANA, of course.

I'd also like to suggest sticking to more conventional encapsulation e.g. within UDP, for best practice.